# Serialize foreign key object that is AbstractUser

Tags: django

I am serializing a model using the Django REST framework successfully, but would like to add a field from a related model. I have seen other posts describe how to do this using nested serializers, however mine is different because the other model I am trying to access is an `AbstractUser` class.
I would like to serialize the `UserDefinedEquipName` field from CustomUser.

models (some fields removed for clarity):

accounts/models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser): 
    UserDefinedEquipName = models.CharField(max_length=50, default = "Default equip",)
    ....
```

builds/models.py

```
from accounts.models import CustomUser
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Build(models.Model):
    author =  models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    machineName = models.OneToOneField(max_length=50,blank=True,)
    ....
```

So my thought is to pass the value into the serializer but can't seem to figure out how to access the value without getting error `AttributeError: type object 'Build' has no attribute 'CustomUser'`

I have tried:
My serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Data, Build, CustomUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class buildStatsAPI_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    equipName = Build.CustomUser.UserDefinedEquipName
    #also tried:
    #equipName = Build.CustomUser__set.all()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('id','author','machineName','equipName',)
    model = Build
```

Am I missing something small here? Or is there a much better way of doing this. It seems like if this wasn't an AbstractUser class it would be much easier.

EDIT - Added views.py

```
class buildStatsAPI(generics.ListCreateAPIView):#for build stats JSON
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = buildStatsAPI_serializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        machinesOwned =CustomUser.objects.filter(customerTag=self.request.user.customerTag).filter(isDevice=True)
        machineList = []
        for machine in machinesOwned:
            machineList = machineList + [machine.id]
        query = Build.objects.filter(deleted=0, author_id__in=machineList,).values().order_by('pk')
        return query
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are defining the Serializer improperly. You can't directly reference Model in a serializer. You need to use any kind of [fields](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields). For example, if you use [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield), you can try like this:

```
class buildStatsAPI_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    equipName = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id','author','machineName','equipName',)
        model = Build

    def get_equipName(self, obj):
        # here obj is a build model object
        return obj.author.UserDefinedEquipName
```

#### Update

Please update your `get_queryset` method so that it returns a queryset like this(I have refactored it a bit):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    query = Build.objects.filter(deleted=0, author__customerTag=self.request.user.customerTag, author__isDevice=True)  # removed .values() because it will return a dictionary
    return query
```

Comment: little bit late, answer. Should i remove my answer ?

Comment: Unfortunately, they are pretty much similar. If you can suggest other solutions, it will be appreciated :) .

Comment: I have deleted my post. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you @Shakil bhai :) . But its upto OP to decide.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses guys. I think it's close but I am getting `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'author'`. Any ideas?

Comment: Sure can - See above. Thanks

Comment: Amazing - Thanks so much for the help @ruddra